# Como executar vários FOR ao mesmo tempo

Tags: java, for

No código abaixo eu tenho *4 for* e eles executam em sequencia, porem eu preciso que eles executem todos ao mesmo tempo.

```
public class main 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long init  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    ataque(999999, 999999);
    long end  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    long diff = end - init;
    System.out.print("Demorou " + (diff / 1000) + " segundos");
}
public static void ataque(int limite, int busca)
{
    int for1 = 0;
    int for2 = limite / 4;
    int for3 = for2 + for2;
    int for4 = for2 = for3;

    for(int i = for1; i < for2; i++)
    {
        /*if(i == busca)
        {
            break;
        }*/

        System.out.println(i + " de " + busca + "\r"); 
    }
    for(int i = for2; i < for3; i++)
    {
        /*if(i == busca)
        {
            break;
        }*/

        System.out.println(i + " de " + busca + "\r"); 
    }
    for(int i = for3; i < for4; i++)
    {
        /*if(i == busca)
        {
            break;
        }*/

        System.out.println(i + " de " + busca + "\r"); 
    }
    for(int i = for4; i < limite; i++)
    {
        /*if(i == busca)
        {
            break;
        }*/

        System.out.println(i + " de " + busca + "\r"); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Você vai ter que usar Threads, segue um link para te dar uma noção: [link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-threads-em-java/28780)

Comment: Porque precisa que sejam ao mesmo tempo? Acho que seu problema é outro.

Comment: Tem que ser realmente ao mesmo tempo? Com exata precisão? Ou apenas terminar e comecar ao mesmo tempo? Esses detalhes pode fazer a diferenca na hora de dizer como solucionar seu problema.

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar 4 *Threads* com `Runnable`. Note que **não** serão exatamente ao mesmo tempo, mas uma não precisará esperar a outra, exemplo:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = for1; i < for2; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + " de " + busca + "\r"); 
        }
    }
}).start();

new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = for2; i < for3; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + " de " + busca + "\r"); 
        }
    }
}).start();
```

No entanto se você realmente necessita que sejam ao mesmo tempo, você terá que criar todos eventos dentro de um único loop e usar uma variável booleana para verificar se ao menos uma das condições entrou em um`IF`:

```
bool testIfs = false;
int increment1 = 0;
int increment2 = 0;

while (true) {
    if (increment1 < for2) {
        //Se entrar na condição então não irá lançar o break
        testIfs = true;

        System.out.println(increment1 + " de " + busca + "\r"); 

        increment1++;
    }

    if (increment2 < for3) {
        //Se entrar na condição então não irá lançar o break
        testIfs = true;

        System.out.println(increment2 + " de " + busca + "\r"); 

        increment2++;
    }

    if (testIfs == false) {
       //Se o loop não entrou em nenhuma das if então é executado o break pra poder parar o loop
       break;
    }

    //Se não houve break então testIfs volta a ser false pra testar novamente o loop
    testIfs = false;
}
```

Neste exemplo, eu apenas adicionei uma duas condições para entender, mas pode-se adicionar várias "ifs".